# Count values from a hierarchy table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is a hierarchy table another is Login table.

The hierarchy table has some heads. FL reports to GH.GH reports to RH. RH reports to NH.
D reports to C
C reports to B
B reports to A

| NH | RH | GH | FL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D |
| A | B | E | F |
| A | K | L | M |
| A | K | L | T |

Login table

| Name | Logintime |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| C | 1 |
| M | 1 |
| L | 3 |

I want to combine those tables and want the output as below table.

total no of person reports to A is -B,K,C,E,L,D,F,M,T = 9  include  A sum is 10
login person -A,C,M,L=4

total no of person reports to B is - C,E,D,F = total 4  include  B sum is 5
login person which are under B (Including B) -C=  total 1

| Name | total_user | login_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 4 |
| B | 5 | 1 |

and so on.

Can anyone help me on the same.
I tried refer this link but it is different.
https://learnsql.com/blog/count-join-sql/
Can anyone suggest anything

Comment: That's an unusual way of modeling hierarchies. The traditional way is to have a two-column table with (`ID` and a reference to its parent `PARENT_ID`). I would consider changing the database design.

Comment: can't we create Id or rank over here for each column like for NH id start from 101 and so on and for Rh starts from 201 and so on using the rank function.

Comment: Though commendable in the sense that writing a SQL query that could work with this second-rate design will take some effort and understanding of SQL, I think it's not worth the effort. It's better to learn SQL and relational algebra with a good database design.